# error messages in dashboard login

Tags: wp-config

I have included the following into my wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

But getting these error messages at the login screen for my WP dashboard:

Notice: Constant FORCE_SSL_LOGIN already defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress01\wp-config.php on line 102

Notice: Constant FORCE_SSL_ADMIN already defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress01\wp-config.php on line 103

Kindly explain why I am getting these error messages and how I can rectify the situation to force ssl login.

Answer (score 4):

See [WordPress Administration over SSL page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL). In there, it says :

> The constant FORCE_SSL_LOGIN can be set to true to force all logins to
>   happen over SSL. This (and all other such definitions) must be placed
>   before
>
> `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`
>
> in the file, otherwise
>   they will not take effect.

I encountered the same problem and moving the code to above the line :

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

in `wp-config.php` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redefine a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

The notice(s) pretty much tell you what's going on. Verbatim.
Check lines 102 & 103. The two constants are defined there. As well as somewhere else.

```
cd /path/to/wordpress/ && grep -r FORCE_SSL .
```

from a *nix shell should reveal those location(s).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I inserted those lines 102 and 103. and that resulted in these error messages. Can you tell me where they can be found predefined?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Xampp for Windows. I can't locate where else these is defined and can't make out how to force ssl login.

Comment: http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use, it first checks if it's already defined, if not, defines it, otherwise doesn't since it's not necessary (or able) to define it again.

```
if (!defined('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN')) { define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', TRUE); }
```